# Animal Crossing New Horizons multiple of the same villagers?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

There is this resident animal I found a small blue bear named Poncho. I was wondering if both me and my friend can have the villager at the same time? I guess what I'm trying to ask is **Can he be on my friends island as well as mine during the same time period?**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, villagers you can have on your island can also be on your friends' islands at the same time.  Do note that your friend will still have to run into him through Mystery Island trips in order to get him, or you can always send him over to his island.

Source: A friend and I both have Snake on our islands :)